# Thousand Separators in View Data Table Highcharter R

Tags: r, highcharts

I've managed to add export plots/data option in my highcharter plots using the following code.

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)

hcoptslang <- getOption("highcharter.lang")
hcoptslang$thousandsSep <- ","
options(
  highcharter.lang = hcoptslang
)

data.frame(
  category = c("A", "B", "C"),
  value = c(1500, 76546, 54579)
) %>% 
  hchart(
    "bar",
    hcaes(
      x = "category",
      y = "value"
    )
  ) %>% 
  hc_exporting(
    enabled = TRUE,
    buttons = list(
      contextButton = list(
        align = 'right'
      )
    ),
    chartOptions = list(
      title = list(
        text = "Test"
      )
    )
  )
```

But the "View Data Table" in exports option shows raw data. If I want to view the numeric columns with thousand separators, what should I do?

Comment: `format(x, big.mark=",")`?

Comment: @rg255 where should I put it?

Comment: no idea - I don't know enough about what you are doing to replicate the problem